# "or" condition in boto3 filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Is there a way to specify an "or" condition between 2 filters in boto3?
For example I'm using the following EC2 service call:

```
ec2.snapshots.filter(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'tag-key',
                'Values': ['SomethingMeaningfull']
            },
            {
                'Name': 'tag:Name',
                'Values': ['OtherMeaningfullThibg']
            },
        ],
        DryRun=False)
```

In this case the filter is evaluated as an "AND" condition, but I would like to have it evaluated as an "OR". Is this something that you can achieve with boto3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters are always applied in an AND combination.

If you need an OR combination, you'll need to execute `ec2:DescribeSnapshots` multiple times, each with your different parts of the OR.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I’m going to do multiple calls in this case.