# Better way write custom filters | Python - AWS - Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

My requirement is to filter based on 2 conditions:

1. Stopped instances
2. Instances with certain tag

I can achieve this by writing 2 separate custom filters, but I want to know if I can achieve the same in single filter.

**My Code:**

```
    stopped_filter = Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}]
    stopped_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=stopped_filter)

    tag_filter = Filters=[{'Name':'tag-key', 'Values':['doaf']}]
    tagged_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=tag_filter)
```

**What I have tried:**

```
    filter = Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}, {'Name':'tag-key', 'Values':['doaf']}]
    stopped_and_tagged_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filter)
```

Comment: thier is an open issue regarding searching with tags: you can watch it [here](https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/718)

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505382/or-condition-in-boto3-filters ?

Comment: Thanks buddy, I have modified my question now..

Comment: There is no conclusion in that discussion it seems.. and also the discussion over there have a slightly different context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
filter = Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}, {'Name':'tag-key', 'Values':['doaf']}]
```

Should be:

```
filter = [{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}, {'Name':'tag-key', 'Values':['doaf']}]
```

Full example:

```py
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
filter = [{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}, {'Name':'tag-key', 'Values':['Foo']}]
stopped_and_tagged_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filter)
print([i.id for i in stopped_and_tagged_instances])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, your script returns the following:
[ec2.Instance(id='i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'), ec2.Instance(id='i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),....] I am looking to extract only 'i-xxxxxxx' part in output. without going for regex.

Comment: It returns a collection of instances. You can extract the instance via `.id`. I've edited my answer to show how. There is _never_ a need for regex because the code is dealing with objects, not strings.